# Access $state inside template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, state

**Background**

I create an app with a menu on the left which contains several menu items. When the user clicks on an item (or access it via an URL), I want to highlight the item (i.e. apply the class 'active' on the corresponding `<li>`).

Note : I handle routes with `ui.router`.

**What I tried**

Up to now, I try to use a `ng-class` directive :

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">

<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li ng-class="{active: current=='container.item1'}">
    <a href="#/a/item1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: current=='container.item2'}">
    <a href="#/a/item2">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: current=='container.item3'}">
    <a href="#/a/item3">Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And on js side :

```
.controller('container', function($scope, $rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
      function(){
        $scope.current = $state.current.name;
      }
  )
})
```

It works quite good but I wondered if it was possible to reference the state directly in the *template*, without having to handle manually the event. Something like :

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li ng-class="{active: $state.current.name =='container.item1'}">
    <a href="#/a/item1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: $state.current.name =='container.item2'}">
    <a href="#/a/item2">Item 2</a>
  </li>
```

(which does not work)

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easy way is to use this:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

and then anywhere we can access `$state` and `$stateParams`, for example like in this template:

```
<div >
  <h3>current state name: <var>{{$state.current.name}}</var></h3>


  <h5>params</h5>
  <pre>{{$stateParams | json}}</pre>
  <h5>state</h5>
  <pre>{{$state.current | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

There is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/4pjoofCXq444kjXLqGx8?p=preview)

Comment: Very interest in this approach for a centralized navigation feature. Thanks Radim