# Set a $stateParam value in scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to automatically set a $scope value in a controller from a state definition?

For example, if I have state definition

```
$stateProvider.state("page", {
  url: "/page", controller: PageController, template: "<div></div>"
}
```

And I navigate to page with a parameter like this:

```
$state.go("page", {param1: 'value1'});
```

Is it possible to inject param1 in PageController $scope using the state definition to be able to call $scope.param1 in PageController and give me the value 'value1'?

Obviously, I can just set it in the PageController with

```
$scope.param1 = $stateParams.param1;
```

But I'm looking to see if I can include this as part of state definition instead (like in the resolve maybe).

Comment: you should able to inject into the $rootScope on app.run like [in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020974/access-state-inside-template).  Similarly you can also use `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {//set to $rootScope here} in app.run function.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**routing :**

```
.state('page', {
      url: '/page',
      template: '<div></div>',
      controller: 'PageController',
      data : {param1 : 'value1'}
  })
```

**PostController :**

```
controller('PageController', function($state, $scope){
      console.log($state.current.data.param1);
})
```